# Error appearing in console with no side effects

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer

I am cleaning up code from another dev and saw this in the console. I am not sure what he was trying to do or what this does.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.alert = function(){};
    var defaultCSS = document.getElementById('bootstrap-css');
    function changeCSS(css){
        if(css) $('head > link').filter(':first').replaceWith('<link rel="stylesheet" href="'+ css +'" type="text/css" />'); 
        else $('head > link').filter(':first').replaceWith(defaultCSS); 
    }
    $( document ).ready(function() {
      var iframe_height = parseInt($('html').height()); 
      window.parent.postMessage( iframe_height, 'http://bootsnipp.com');
    });
</script>
```

I am getting the following Error in my console.

> Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow': The target origin
>   provided ('http://bootsnipp.com') does not match the recipient
>   window's origin ('null').

More importantly what is the code actually trying to accomplish? I inherited this project from someone else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my guess:

For some reason, this is overwriting the regular `alert` function with an empty function.

The `changeCSS` function is defined here, but not used here. It might be used elsewhere.

As for the `postMessage`, I assume this is in an IFRAME of some sorts?